# My custom Magento module won't return a category list

Tags: magento

The normal way to get the store categories is:

```
$helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$categories = $helper->getStoreCategories();
```

But when I use this in my custom admin module, it returns an
empty array. How can I use the category tree in an custom
admin module?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<?php
$helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$categories = $helper->getStoreCategories('name', true, false);
   //or below code
$categories = $helper->getStoreCategories('name', false, false);
?>
```

Comment: I just tried this. If I test it in my admin page, and I count $categories it returns 0. It I test it on another page (not admin) and I count $categories, it returns 365.